# MySql Query Multiple Records

Tags: mysql, sql, tf-idf

i have following query for tf/idf measurement . My aim is to get top 10  for each date like top 10 for 20160401, top 10 for 20160402 etc.But according to my query i have more than 10 for each date.As it can see i could not get ordered, there should be only one 1 , one 2 one 3 , i mean max 10 for each date.

```
date     word rowNumber

20160401 word     1
20160401 word     2 
..
20160401 word     10 

-------------------
20160402 word     1
20160402 word     2 
..
20160402 word     10
```

The following is my query for tf idf measurement.  in newsdetails   table i have  columns and values like

```
   date        word     wordCount
 20160401    yürürlük      1
 20160401    mülteci       1
 20160401    anlaşma       2
 20160401    pazartesi     1
 20160401    itibaren      1
 20160401    uygula        2

-------------------

      SELECT t.newsCreatedTime,t.word,t.tf_idf as tweetRatio ,rn
       FROM (
       select w.newsCreatedTime,w.word,w.wordCount,t1.topic_sum,w.wordCount/t1.topic_sum as tf, 
             t2.idf,(w.wordCount/t1.topic_sum)*(t2.idf) as tf_idf,
          (@rn := if(@t = w.newsCreatedTime, @rn + 1,
                     if(@t := w.newsCreatedTime, 1, 1)
                    )
          ) as rn
       FROM newsdetails  w JOIN
       ( select newsCreatedTime, sum(wordCount) as topic_sum 
        from newsdetails where trim(word)<>'limit' and length(trim(word))>3 and  newsCreatedTime>=20160401
        group by newsCreatedTime 
       ) t1
        on w.newsCreatedTime=t1.newsCreatedTime  and trim(w.word)<>'limit' and length(trim(w.word))>3 and  w.newsCreatedTime>=20160401
        join (
          select w.word, log10(t_cnts.cnts/count(*)) as idf 
          from newsdetails w,
          (select count(distinct newsCreatedTime) as cnts from newsdetails where trim(word)<>'limit' and length(trim(word))>3 and  newsCreatedTime>=20160401) t_cnts
          group by w.word 
          ) t2 
         on w.word=t2.word CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT @t := '', @rn := 0) params 
        ORDER BY tf_idf desc 
       ) t
       WHERE rn <=10
```

The output is :

```
  Date        word            ratio           rowNumber

20160401    kadın        -0.0005375613007471833      1
20160401    beyaz        -0.00006167450024777626     1
20160401    alışveriş    -0.000015563777946653284    1
20160401    ösym          0                          1
20160401    yürürlük      0.00004586823255826781     1
20160401    haber        -0.0003304889014365445      2
20160401    taraf        -0.00019041987363584725     2
20160401    merkezi      -0.00013800691483414033     2
20160401    mülteci      -0.000056636107108483694    2
20160401    perde         0.00004941253963307586     2
20160401    sınav        -0.00017806007150496475     3
```

But i want to get  only top 10 word for each date with their ratio.

Comment: Looks like you need to limit row number inside your subqueries

Comment: actually i miss that point , which statement do you mean ? @DanielMarcus

Comment: Im saying in subqueries t1, t2 etc limit your data to top ten

Comment: one is working for sum and the other one is working for count, if i use limit 10 then just 10 records will be selected. i need all records but 10 for each date. @DanielMarcus

Comment: Ok I think I get what you are saying in that case wrap up your whole query into a subquery and then select rownumber partition by date order by ratio where rownumber<=10

Comment: @DanielMarcus i miss again :) forgive me . now i will put this query into another one then ? i miss that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work in SQL Server - May have to adjust syntax for MySQL

```
select * from(
select *, row_number() over(partition by date order by ratio) rownum from (SELECT t.newsCreatedTime,t.word,t.tf_idf as tweetRatio ,rn
       FROM (
       select w.newsCreatedTime,w.word,w.wordCount,t1.topic_sum,w.wordCount/t1.topic_sum as tf, 
             t2.idf,(w.wordCount/t1.topic_sum)*(t2.idf) as tf_idf,
          (@rn := if(@t = w.newsCreatedTime, @rn + 1,
                     if(@t := w.newsCreatedTime, 1, 1)
                    )
          ) as rn
       FROM newsdetails  w JOIN
       ( select newsCreatedTime, sum(wordCount) as topic_sum 
        from newsdetails where trim(word)<>'limit' and length(trim(word))>3 and  newsCreatedTime>=20160401
        group by newsCreatedTime 
       ) t1
        on w.newsCreatedTime=t1.newsCreatedTime  and trim(w.word)<>'limit' and length(trim(w.word))>3 and  w.newsCreatedTime>=20160401
        join (
          select w.word, log10(t_cnts.cnts/count(*)) as idf 
          from newsdetails w,
          (select count(distinct newsCreatedTime) as cnts from newsdetails where trim(word)<>'limit' and length(trim(word))>3 and  newsCreatedTime>=20160401) t_cnts
          group by w.word 
          ) t2 
         on w.word=t2.word CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT @t := '', @rn := 0) params 
        ORDER BY tf_idf desc 
       ) t
       WHERE rn <=10 )a)b where rownum<=10
```